# Coordinate curves are geodesics

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, surfaces, parametrization, geodesic

Given a regular surface $S$ and a point $p \in S$, does there always exist a parametrization $x(u,v)$ of some neighborhood $V$ of $p$, such that the coordinate curves $u=\text{constant}$ and $v=\text{constant}$ are geodesics?

Any help\hint will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please do not post homework/exam questions with absolutely zero effort. Even having written my own differential geometry text and taught the course twenty times, I cannot begin to guess what tools you have at your disposal to approach this problem. So you're going to have to make some efforts and show us what you know.

Comment: Hi Professor Shifrin, Sorry that I forgot to clarify, but this is some claim I came up by myself when reading example 5 on page 255 of Do Carmo's book, where he proved that meridians are geodesics in a surface of evolution. I'm not sure whether my claim is correct or not....what I have tried is to use the differential equations of the geodesics...but it still seems hard to construct a parametrization with some vanishing Christoffel symbols...

Comment: OK. Here are some exercises for you (not necessarily easy): (1) If you have $u$- and $v$-curves all geodesics and at a constant angle (say $\pi/2$ for starters), then $S$ must be flat. (2) You can always find a parametrization with the $u$-curves geodesics and everywhere orthogonal to the $v$-curves; the $v$-curves will generally not be geodesics. (3) Make the $u$-curves geodesics and take the $v$-curves to be geodesics you get starting perpendicular to a given $u$-curve (so in general they will not stay perpendicular).

Comment: Hi Professor Shifirn, I have thought about the problems you proposed above for a while, but I haven't finished most of them...However, when I was reading Chapter 4-6 of Do Carmo's book, it seems that if I pick the parametrization to be geodesic polar coordinates, then my question gets resolved. Is that correct?

Comment: I see...thank you so much!! but essentially here we only need to make the two Christoffel symbols $\Gamma_{11}^{2}$ and $\Gamma_{22}^{1}$ vanish in our parametrization right, by the differential equation of geodesics?

Comment: Yes, that sounds right!

Comment: I see....previously I thought of using the orthogonal parametrization...but it seems that we still need to exert some extra conditions to make the two symbols equal to zero (like making $E$ independent of $v$ and $G$ independent of $u$...) Would that be a possible approach?

Comment: Yes, but do that exercise. This can happen only with zero Gaussian curvature!

Comment: My earlier comment should have said merely that geodesic circles are a constant distance from the center point, certainly not themselves geodesics. By the way, for my exercises, you will want to use the theorem on p. 182 of DoCarmo.

Comment: Hi Professor Shifirn, Thank you so much for your help, and I'm sorry for keeping following up. Would you please clarify a little bit more on (3) of your exercise? I think using the theorem you proposed above I can solve (2), but I'm bit confused with the meaning of "starting perpendicular to....." in (3). Also, how do all these help resolve my hypothesis?

Comment: @TedShifrin Hi professor Shifirn, sorry to ask you again, but for my hypothesis, would it be possible for me to combine the differential equation of geodesics with corollary 1 in chapter 3-4 (page 183) of Do Carmo's book? I think the ODEs determine some integral curves, and it suffices to parametrize x based on these integral curves right?

Comment: I think the theorem is directly applicable, but no big deal. (1) is the most interesting, because of curvature constraints. But, yes, (3) does answer your question. In (3) you can start any way you want so long as the chosen initial directions are not tangent to the “starting” $u$-curve.

Comment: @TedShifrin I see...thank you so much for your detailed response! May I ask you a follow-up question? I found that exercise 12 on page 261 (chapter 4-4 of do carmo's book) is actually pretty similar to my hypothesis, while they add an extra condition (i.e, the geodesics are orthogonal). I was wondering if we only assume that the coordinate curves are unit-speed geodesics, can we also deduce that the gaussian curvature is everywhere 0 in V?

Comment: sorry for the last part of my comment I mean "everywhere zero in V"

Comment: I think you should write up an answer to your original question and then post this last one as a new question (if you can't figure it out).